# How to make an image inside a diamond shape morph to circle

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I've been experimenting a lot over the past couple of days with CSS and SVGs to try and achieve this effect.

I have a diamond shaped image and when the user hovers over it should morph into a circle and ideally the image should change to a block colour.

I thought at first I could do it using SVG and I managed to get an SVG diamond to morph into a circle but the next step was to have an image/block colour and I thought masks might be the way to go! The closest I got was:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByaaqE

HTML

```
<div>
  <span></span>
  <img src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5607/5091629.6b/0_612e6_b9039c0d_M.jpg" alt="" />  
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at center);
    -moz-clip-path: circle(100px, 100px, 100px);
    clip-path: circle(100px, 100px, 100px);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 200px; height: 300px;
}

div:hover {
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(40px at center);
    -moz-clip-path: circle(40px, 40px, 40px);
    clip-path: circle(40px, 40px, 40px);
}

span {
    display: block;
    width: 200px; height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: background-color 0.7s ease;
}

div:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I could animate a circle but the moment I tried to make it a rectangle it wouldn't work (and I hadn't even managed to look at the diamond shape!).

**I've also tried using a pure CSS method** - although that comes with its own set of problems. I applied the styling on the img tag and it works how I want it but obviously the image is rotated. When I tried to put the image inside a div and rotate the image back to normal it had issues. When hovered over the image didn't go inside the circle despite having overflow hidden on the DIV.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEOMem

It also has the problem of not having the overlay colour on hover.

I was wondering if anyone has managed to do this effect before and if they could shed some light on it and what my best options would be as I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: The diamond shape will be tricky, but maybe this helps on the way: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEOMgG

Comment: Thanks Paul, that was really helpful! Using your pen this is what I came up with!

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYWbpq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This intrigued me so I thought I'd have a bash.

`backface-visibility: hidden;` is the key to preventing the image from overflowing it's parent as mentioned in your question.

You can use a pseudo element (`:before`) for your colour overlay:

```css
/* FIRST EXAMPLE */
.wrap {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 150px 0 0 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease .3s;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.morph {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
  float: left;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.wrap:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(207, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.wrap:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrap:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="morph"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about the backface visibility and I completely forgot about utilizing :before. Thank you, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Using your code I removed the float and changed the div to an inline-block as it didn't seem to have a noticeable effect and then I also added some initials that would appear over it (which will be relevant to the site). Positioning is a bit strange once you rotate but I'm guessing thats because the anchor point changes. http://jsfiddle.net/brrv5k8o/